# Converting from Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> to Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, expression

The following code is generating an error:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditControlFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
{
    ModelMetadata metadata = GetModelMetaData(htmlHelper, expression);
    Type propertyType = GetPropertyType(metadata);

    if (propertyType.IsEnum)
    {
        return DropDownListForEnum(htmlHelper, expression);
    }
    else if (propertyType == typeof(bool))
    {
        return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(expression);
    }
    else
    {
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression);
    }
}
```

The compile time error is below:

```
Error: cannot convert from 
'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,TProperty>>' 
to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,bool>>'.
```

It looks like CheckBoxFor() is expecting a parameter of type :

```
Expression<Func<TModel, bool>>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of the `propertyType == typeof(bool)` test, it should already be the right thing - you just need to convince the compiler that your intentions are honest. In this case, via:

```
var typedExpression = (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,bool>>)(object)expression;
return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(typedExpression);
```

Comment: var typedExpression = (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TModel,bool>>)(object)expression; return htmlHelper.CheckBoxFor(typedExpression); will work when the type is boolean. If the property passed in is a nullable boolean it throws an error. Any ideas?